# when referring to 'Number Crunching', how intensive is 'intensive'?

Tags: language-agnostic

I am currently reading / learning Erlang, and it is often noted that it is not (really) suitable for 'heavy number crunching'. Now I often come across this phrase or similar, but never really know what 'heavy' exactly means.

How does one decide if an operation is computationally intensive? Can it be quantified before testing?

Edit:

is there a difference between the quantity of calculations, the complexity of the algorithm or the size of the input values.

for example `1000 computaions of 28303 / 4` vs `100 computations of 239847982628763482 / 238742`

Comment: Why are you learning Erlang? Chances are you are learning it to 1) Learn a functional language 2) Learn a language that's really good at concurrency and stability 3) *Not* make games, brute force passwords or do physical simulations in it. So there's no real worry. But aside from that it's an interesting question, so +1 for you, sir. :)

Comment: hei Anders, I'm learning it as I am generally interested in `(1)` - i also try to play with clojure and haskell as well, but for erlang it is really option `(2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are talking about Erlang specifically, I doubt that you in general want to develop applications that require intensive number crunching with it. That is - you don't learn Erlang to code a physics engine in it. So don't worry about Erlang being too slow for you.

Moving from Erlang to the question in general, these things almost always come down to relativity. Let's ignore number crunching and ask a general question about programming: **How fast is fast enough?**

Well, *fast enough* depends on:

- what you want to do with the application
- how often you want to do it
- how fast your users expect it to happen

If reading a file in some program takes 1ms or 1000ms - is 1000 ms to be considered "too slow"?

If ten files have to be read in quick succession - yes, probably way too slow. Imagine an XML parser that takes 1 second to simply read an XML file from disk - horrible!

If a file on the other hand only has to be read when a user manually clicks a button every 15 minutes or so then it's not a problem, e.g. in Microsoft Word.

The reason nobody says exactly what *too slow* is, is because it doesn't really matter. The same goes for your specific question. A language should rarely, if ever, be shunned for being "slow".

And last but not least, if you develop some monstrous project in Erlang and, down the road, realise that *dagnabbit!* you really need to crunch those numbers - then you do your research, find good libraries and implement algorithms in the language best suited for it, and then interop with that small library.

Comment: I definitely feel that polyglot is the way to go in a large system. All languages have their sweet spots and in a large system different parts will have different requirements, it is unlikely that one language will be the best at everything. So do as @AndersHolmström suggests, **when necessary** find a good library and interface to it.

Answer (score 2):

i once asked a question about number crunching in couch DB mapreduce: [CouchDB Views: How much processing is acceptable in map reduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046285/couchdb-views-how-much-processing-is-acceptible-in-map-reduce)

whats interesting in one of the answers is this:

> suppose you had 10,000 documents and they take 1 second each to
>   process (which is way higher than I have ever seen). That is 10,000
>   seconds or 2.8 hours to completely build the view. However once the
>   view is complete, querying any row (?key=...) or row slice
>   (?startkey=...&endkey=...) takes the same time as querying for
>   documents directly. Lookup time is O(log n) for the document count.
>
> In other words, even if it takes 1 second per document to execute the
>   map, it will take a few milliseconds to fetch the result. (Of course,
>   the view must build first, since it is actually an index.)

I think if you think about your current question in those terms, its an interesting angle to think of your question. on the topic of the language's speed / optimization:

> How does one decide if an operation is computationally intensive?

Facebook asked this question about PHP, and ended up writing [HIP HOP](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2010/02/02/hiphop-for-php--move-fast/) to solve the problem -- it compiles PHP into C++. They said *the reason php is much slower than C++ is because the PHP language is all dynamic lookup*, and therefore much processing is required to do anything with variables, arrays, dynamic typing (which is a source of slowdown), etc.

So, a question you can ask is: *is erlang dynamic-lookup? static typing? compiled?*

> is there a difference between the quantity of calculations, the
>   complexity of the algorithm or the size of the input values. For
>   example 1000 computaions of 28303 / 4 vs 100 computations of
>   239847982628763482 / 238742

So, with that said, the fact that you can even grant specific types to numbers of different kinds means you SHOULD be using the right types, and that will definitely cause performance increase.

Answer (score 2):

With this sort of thing you'll know it when you see it! Usually this refers to situations when it matters if you pick an int, float, double etc. Things like physical simulations or monte carlo methods, where you want to do millions of calculations.

To be honest, in reality you just write those bits in C and use your favourite other language to run them.

Answer (score 0):

suitability for number-crunching depends on the library support and inherent nature of the language. for example, a pure functional language will not allow any mutable variables, which makes it extremely interesting to implement any equation solving type problems. Erlang probably falls in to this category.